# How to know when a newly pushed screen is fully transitioned on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Problem: Let's say there are only 2 screens. When a second screen is pushed on the first one, animation of transition jitters and is not smooth. The reason is that second screen has a very costly widgets. I am trying to wait till a transition animation finishes completely and then render costly widgets. Currently, I am just delaying using

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
```

---

What I am trying to achieve

```
 class SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initialize();
  }

  initialize() async {
    await waitTillTransitionFinishes;

    loadCostlyWidgets;
  }
}
```

---

I am navigating like below

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => SecondScreen()
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        loadCostlyWidgets;
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but my transition animation still jitters. It did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModalRoute.of(context)?.animation to obtain the current page's  animation and listen for completion, as follows:

```dart
class SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  Animation<double>? get transitionIn => ModalRoute.of(context)?.animation;
  bool isWidgetVisible = false;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      transitionIn?.addStatusListener(_handleTransitionCompletion);
    });
  }

  void _handleTransitionCompletion(AnimationStatus status) {
    if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
      transitionIn?.removeStatusListener(_handleTransitionCompletion);
      setState(() {
        isWidgetVisible = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

A full example can be found here:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=57e57e674293dd72bca1340e9e8ebac6

Good luck!